# pip not working and apt cannot reinstall python using kali 2019.4 on vmware

Tags: apt, python, kali-linux, pip

I installed kali 2019.4 from kali.org on a vmware machine. However, pip does not seem to be installed and I can't find the answer on how to install it.
Note: I am forwarded to the internet by a proxy.

I Set up the variables:

```
http_proxy=x.x.x.x:port    
https_proxy=x.x.x.x:port    
export http_proxy=x.x.x.x:port    
export http_proxy=x.x.x.x:port
```

I know the settings are good becuase:

```
wget --spider www.google.com
Proxy request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
```

Here is how i know pip is not installed:

```
python3 -m pip install requests
No module named pip

python -m pip install requests
No module named pip

pip --version
pip: command not found

pip3 --version
pip: command not found
```

And this is what I did to try and fix it: (reinstalling python(3))

```
apt get python3-pip

E: Package 'python3-pip' has no installation candidate


apt get python-pip

E: Unable to locate package python-pip


apt install --reinstall python3
Reinstallation of python3 is not possible, it cannot be downloaded.
```

Any help is reccomended, thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you set up your proxy variables are incorrect, setting them as:

```
http_proxy=x.x.x.x:port
```

will set them as variables in you current console session.
when using export try defining them as:

```
export http_proxy=http://x.x.x.x:port
```

However your main problem seems to be that the package just cannot be found.
you could try adding a repository that contains it to /etc/apt/sources.list
or by downloading the deb package directly and installing it using dpkg

```
dpkg -i <PACKAGE>
```

package:
https://packages.debian.org/jessie/python3-pip

Answer (score 0):

You had the right package name (**python3-pip**), but the wrong install command.

For python 2.x:

```
sudo apt install python-pip
```

For python 3.x:

```
sudo apt install python3-pip
```

Comment: Tried it, didn't work.
E: Unable to locate package python(3)-pip.

[Screenshot](https://imgur.com/y09RFVH)